# How many of the 66 were saved?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Considering this movie was all about purging the Jedi clan, by the later second half, Palpatine orders all his followers/Stormtroopers to execute all 66. Of the 66, how many were actually saved/rescued?
[image]

Comment: See [How many Jedi were there at the time of the purge?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40252/70236) and [Number of Jedi after Order 66?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3536/70236) over at [scifi.se].

Comment: Order 66 doesn't mean there were 66 Jedi. There's Order 65 which contains provisions of removing chancellor by lethal force. It doesn't mean there were 65 chancellors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Palpatine orders all his followers/Stormtroopers to execute all 66

### You misheard...

The quote is..

> Execute **Order** 66

> Order 66 was an event at the end of the Clone Wars in which the clone troopers of the Grand Army of the Republic turned against their Jedi commanders and terminated them, bringing about the destruction of the Jedi Order..[snip]...caused clone troopers to violently lash out at the Jedi and view them as traitors,
>
> <sup>[**Wookiepedia**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_66)</sup>

As for how many survived the purge I would recommend a couple of Q&A over on Science Fiction & Fantasy. <sup>Thanks to @Gallifreyan</sup>

[How many Jedi were there at the time of the purge?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40252/how-many-jedi-were-there-at-the-time-of-the-purge)

and

[Number of Jedi after Order 66?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/number-of-jedi-after-order-66)